# How to prevent unwind from unwinding fields removed with $project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use unwind in the following code but this results in a list longer than expected .

For instance:The lookup returns an array with 6 objects and after performing the unwind, it returns 20+ documents in the app and 10 in mongodb Atlas (I guess this is the max since it's the example window).

What I really need is that the unwind only returns the original 6 documents but with the subject array dispersed in all of them.(Which kinda does except that it repeats the documents)

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'student': '63938a5202c86f10ad890740'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'student': 1, 
      'partialGrades': 1, 
      'finalGrade': 1, 
      'group': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'classrooms', 
      'localField': 'group', 
      'foreignField': 'group', 
      'as': 'subject'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'subject.teacher': 0, 
      'subject.group': 0, 
      'subject._id': 0
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$subject', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': false
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: In the queried collection, how many documents have `'student': '63938a5202c86f10ad890740'`?